# Bank Simulator - doBusiness method help LinkedList/Queue

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

So I have to create a Bank Simulator project for class, and so far I have a few of the methods implemnted. But currently I am having trouble with the doBusiness method in the ServiceCenter class. Here is the code I have so far.

Main: BankSimulator

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankSimulator {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the time duration (in minutes) to be simulated? ");
    int maxTime = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What percentage of the time (0-100) does a customer arrive? ");
    int arrivalProb = input.nextInt();

    ServiceCenter bank = new ServiceCenter();
    while (bank.getTime() <= maxTime || bank.customersRemaining()) {
        if (bank.getTime() <= maxTime && customerArrived(arrivalProb)) {
            bank.addCustomer();
        }
        bank.doBusiness();
    }
    //bank.displayStats();
}

private static boolean customerArrived(int prob)
{
    return (Math.random()*100 <= prob);
}
}
```

Server class:

```
public class Server {
private static int nextID = 1;
private int serverID;
private int endTime;
private Customer serving;

 public Server()
 {
    serverID = nextID;
    nextID++;
    endTime = 0;
    serving = null;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for getting the server ID number.
 *   @return the server ID
 */
public int getID()
{
    return serverID;
}

/**
 * Assigns a customer to the server and begins the transaction.
 *   @param c the new customer to be served
 *   @param time the time at which the transaction begins
 */
public void startCustomer(Customer c, int time)
{
    serving = c;
    endTime = time + c.getJobLength();
}

/**
 * Accessor method for getting the current customer.
 *   @return the current customer, or null if no customer
 */
public Customer getCustomer()
{
    return serving;
}

/**
 * Identifies the time at which the server will finish with
 * the current customer
 *   @return time at which transaction will finish, or 0 if no customer
 */
public int busyUntil()
{
    return endTime;
}

/**
 * Finishes with the current customer and resets the time to completion.
 */
public void finishCustomer()
{
    serving = null;
    endTime = 0;
}
}
```

Customer class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Customer {
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 8;
private static final Random rand = new Random();
private static int nextID = 1;

private int customerID;
private int arrivalTime;
private int jobLength;

/**
 * Constructs a customer with the next available ID number,
 * the specified arrival time, and a random job length.
 *   @param arrTime the time at which the customer arrives
 */
public Customer(int arrTime)
{
    customerID = nextID;
    nextID++;
    arrivalTime = arrTime;
    jobLength = rand.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH)+1;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for getting the customer's ID number.
 *   @return the customer ID
 */
public int getID()
{
    return customerID;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for getting the customer's arrival time.
 *   @return the time at which the customer arrived
 */
public int getArrivalTime()
{
    return arrivalTime;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for getting the length of the job
 *   @return the job length (in minutes)
 */
public int getJobLength()
{
    return jobLength;
}
}
```

I had to create the following class called ServiceCenter where getTime returns the time in the simulation which starts at 0 and increments on each step. An addCustomer method where we add a customer to the queue and displayed a message. A customerRemaining which returns true if a customer is currently being waited on. Lastly the doBusiness method which increments the time, if the server finished with a customer remove them from the queue, and if the server is free and there is a customer in the queue, begin serving them. I have the first few ones done except the doBusiness method I am stuck on. Does anyone have any tips?

The code listed above was created by Dave Reed and I take no credit for the code.

ServiceCenter class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ServiceCenter {

private int arrivalTime, departureTime;
private Queue <Customer> customer;
private Server server;
public ServiceCenter()
{
    server = new Server();
    customer = new LinkedList <Customer> ();
}

public String addCustomer ()
{   
    Customer customer1 = new Customer (arrivalTime);
    customer.add(customer1);
    String result = "" + customer1.getArrivalTime() + "" + customer1.getID() + "" + customer1.getJobLength();
    return result;
}

public void doBusiness()
{
    if(!customer.isEmpty())
    {
        if(server == null)
        {
            customer.remove();
        }
    }
}

public int getTime()
{
    return departureTime - arrivalTime;
}

public boolean customersRemaining()
{
    if (!(customer.isEmpty()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

Any help at all or tips would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure it out for a week now, but for some reason queues are my weakness. Thanks for reading and sorry for it being so long. Just wanted it to be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `new Customer (arrivalTime);` but you don't have the arrivalTime in your constructor of the ServiceCenter-class.